# Run a script every time there is a change in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to run this sript every time there is a change in `notes!C4` and automatically copy the value to `notes!D4` cell

```
function Copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("notes") ;
  ss.getRange('notes!C4').copyTo(ss.getRange('notes!D4'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

### Update 1

If this it can't be done, I have in another spreadsheet a script that copies the link `http://openinsider.com/screener?s=` every time I run it to `L2` cell of that sheet.

I'm taking that value with an `=ImportRange` to the actual spreadsheet. How can I copy that link to `notes!D4` that's in another spreadsheet to the actual one?

```
function Refresh() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1") ;
  var cell = ss.getRange("L2");
  cell.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(5000); // You have 5 second to check that the cell has cleared
  cell.setValue('http://openinsider.com/screener?s='); 
}
```

### Update 2

I've tried this, the first time the script was charging but it didn't make anything. I'm new to google scripts and I don't know how to make it working.

```
function onEdit(e) { 

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C4') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("notes").getRange('D4').CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is not such a trigger available for that action.  [The available event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Read the reference I gave you.  The  only triggers available trigger on user edits.

Comment: I once had a digital camera that would generate an interupt everytime the image it was focusing on changed.  You could use it to trigger an arduino to send an http request to a web app end point to call an api that runs a google apps script that perform the function you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried onEdits but I don't know how to make it work. Respect the second comment, I'm just starting in coding, so I know practically nothing.

Comment: It would be wise for you to learn JavaScript first it may take you several months but in the long run it will be worth it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Cooper, you just need to use [onEdit(e) Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to run your script whenever there is a cell being modified.

I will just refer on your latest update, you can refer to this sample code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;

  if(cell.getA1Notation() === "C4" && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "notes"){
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("D4").setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

**What it does?**

1. Get the [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object using [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `source` parameter
2. Get the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object using [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `range` parameter
3. Check if the modified cell is in sheet `notes` and in cell `C4`, I get the [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object using [Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet) method and get its sheet name using [Sheet.getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname). This will make sure that your function will only run when Sheet `notes!C4` was modified.
4. Set the value of the cell `D4` using [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue). To maximize the event object, I used `value` parameter in [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).

---

**Additional Tips:**

Please be mindful of the methods available in each classes/objects that you are using. For example in this code:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("notes").getRange('D4').CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;`

- You get the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object of cell `D4` using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object doesn't have `CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES` in its [methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#methods)